# Storing letters in Java in a way allowing them to change?

Tags: java

I am currently making a Noughts and Crosses game in console, and I've run into a problem, since both chars and Strings are constant, their values can't be changed and I've therefore searched all over the web for a way to store letters in such a way I can change them.
I would really appreciate some help or alternative methods of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with variables?

Comment: don't really understand the problem here. why can't you just put a new value into char or string variable if you want to change it?

Answer (score 4):

Keep your board in an array. You can use a `char[3][3]`, for example. You can change any member of an array, for example `board[1][1] = 'O';`

Answer (score 1):

You should make an `Enum` called, perhaps, `NoughtOrCross` as follows:

```
public enum NoughtOrCross {
    NOUGHT,
    CROSS;
}
```

Then put your board in an array declared like this:

```
NoughtOrCross[][] board = new NoughtOrCross[3][3];
```

`null` represents nothing, `NoughtOrCross.NOUGHT` means nought, and `NoughtOrCross.CROSS` means cross.

Comment: enums are immutable in the same way chars and strings are in Java, so that doesn't help with the question at all (it may still be a good idea, but for other reasons).